# Magento ECG discourage $_FILES superglobal

Tags: magento-1.9, coding-standards

I'm using the magento ECG coding standards on a project and am getting the 
following:

`ERROR   | Direct use of $_FILES Superglobal detected.`

I've grepped through the code and can see that [core uses the $_FILES superglobal](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php#L145),  does magento have a wrapper function for this or should i ignore the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use below in place of `$_FILES`

```
try {
    $uploader = Mage::getModel('core/file_uploader', 'field_name');
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'));
    $result = $uploader->save($path); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

To know more what possibly can be done with this approach, go to `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php`

Hope it helps.